# google chrome suddenly deleted my user profile and doesn't save it when I recreate it?

Tags: google-chrome, save, profile

I ran into a very weird problem lately, I'm using google chrome with three profiles, two of which are enterprise google apps. Suddenly one of them got deleted across all my devices (linux, windows 8 and os x 10.9). When I try to re-create the user and login it goes ok (all apps and data and synced) until I exit chrome, at which my login info is deleted and I have to recreate a user every time I launch chrome.

this happens across all devices, I tried uninstalling, reinstalling, chrome canary, chromium, stop and clear (from the google dashboard in chrome settings)
no luck

this happens only on a specific user, one of the google apps enterprise. I revisited the account permissions (i have admin access) and there are no settings related (like don't allow saving profiles or mandate login on every session)

this only happens on MY profile and non of the co-workers

does anyone have a hint on how to clear this issue ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

We found out that there's an ephemeral profile setting in the google apps admin console. It was switched on without our notice so everyone in the company suffered, but when properly set everything is fine

Comment: FYI: You can accept your own answer if you figured it out yourself! Just mark the check mark to the left of your answer :D